# Parsing Java code with Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Is it possible to parse some Java code with a regex?

So let's say I want a list of the `int` variables from this:

```java
int abc1 = 1;
int abc2 = abc1 + 1;
int abd3 = abc1 + abc2;
```

And I want to put these into an `ArrayList`.

So something like this:

```java
private void parse(String s){

    List<List<String>> variables = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    list.add(new ArrayList<String>);//var type
    list.add(new ArrayList<String>);//var name
    list.add(new ArrayList<String>);//var data

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile();//This is what I want
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while(m.find()){
        String match = m.group();
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile();//Here as well
        Matcher m2 = p.matcher(s);
        while(m2.find()){
            for(int i = 0; i < m.groupCount()){
                //add the variables to the lists
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am asking is what regex could possibly handle this task?

---

The reason for all this is so the user can take a bit of control over the application using a bit of code (an Android Application btw)

If it isn't recommended to use a regex, then what parser should I be using?

Comment: Just as a comment, there are many [java parsers](http://www.google.com/?q=java+parser) available. I wouldn't try to juggle with regex to do that.

Comment: whats the motivation behind this ??

Comment: You cannot parse a recursive grammar with regular expressions. Use a parser.

Comment: @Vlad Im sure with enough motivation I could write something to do the job for me, I didn't know that there were parsers for java that parse java however, sounds kinda stupid really haha. Read the last part if you want to know my motivation

Comment: @SmartLemon: no, it's just theoretically impossible. Regexps cannot handle recursive grammars.

Comment: hmm, I see, guess its gonna be a parser then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People often try to parse HTML, XML, C or java with regular expressions.

With enough efforts and tricks, lot of amazing things are possible with complex combinations of regex. But you always end up with something very incomplete and not efficient.

Regex can't handle complex grammars, use a parser, either generic or [specific to java](https://www.google.com/?q=java+parser).

Answer (score 6):

You would probably want to use a more advanced grammar parsing application than regex. You could for example look into [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) which also has various grammars available.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with regular expressions, but it may be easier to user a Java Parser. You can try [JavaCC](http://java.net/projects/javacc).

Comment: You can *waste your time* trying with a regex, but you *will not succeed*. This was proven in 1956. Using a parser is not just 'easier', it is essential.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you look into parser generators, eg. JavaCC. JavaCC lets you describe the grammar in an BNF-like style and creates Java classes according to it.
There are also already grammars available for JavaCC to parse Java code, I think even as an example or tutorial that comes with JavaCC.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to use regex then try something like `(?<=int )\\w+`, but I strongly advise using some Java parser.