# Java Regex to match Strings and Chars with ' " '

Tags: java, regex, string, char, jtextpane

I am creating a simple IDE to color my JTextPane according to source code. Currently, I am able to match:

- Comments (// & /* */)
- Strings (" ")
- Numbers (Integers & Decimals)
- Keywords (e.g. public / protected ..)

**Q1: I would like to include char coloring the same way as strings. For example: char c = 'a';**

Am i supposed to change my string regular expression to cater for char detection too?

After much testing, I detected a scenario that will mess up my String detection coloring is when a user enters char c = ' " '; The 2nd string that gets detected will detect it as part of the 1st string **(Example shown below.**

My string coloring messes up my whole IDE coloring :(

This is how i detect string patterns and set color to it:

```
Pattern strings = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"");
Matcher matcherS = strings.matcher(text);
while (matcherS.find())
    setCharacterAttributes(matcherS.start(), matcherS.end() - matcherS.start(), red, false);
```

Below is a sample output from my IDE:

[image]

**Q2: Am i supposed to edit my String detection regex to solve this error?**

Thanks in advance.

In case anyone finds in helpful, I got my String IDE detection regex from:

[Which is the right regular expression to use for Numbers and Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299328/which-is-the-right-regular-expression-to-use-for-numbers-and-strings)

Comment: If i can attain both char and string coloring just through 1 regex matching that would be the most ideal situation.

Comment: Pay attention to bullet number 4: http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile("((?<!\\\\)\\\"(.*?)\\\"(?<!\\\\\\\"))");
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/kT4oZ1/1

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a ready made library for that like below:

https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea